# how to change a method signature dynamically in java any utiltiy

Tags: java

I wanted to refactor a method signature of a java class using utility classes E.g.:

*Test.java*

```
public class{

    public void test(int a, int b) {
    .....
    ....
    }

}
```

In my entire project, I wanted to change the methods with the above signature to a different one like below:

```
public void test(String str) {
..
}
```

**without** opening all the files and rewriting them.

`antlr` is used to convert code written in one language to another language.

**I wanted to do these kind of refactoring using java utility kind of class where i will provide my input class as argument and refactoring patters as another argument.i have explored using codemodel and eclipse AST but no luck.**

Comment: How would you change the two `int` arguments into a single `String`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that goes for the function code as well as calls to the function. Worth mentioning... :-)

Comment: Current IDEs should be able to help you with that (I am thinking of Eclipse and IntelliJ - possibly NetBeans too) - I use IntelliJ and it definitely does that kind of refactoring.  It even asks you what default value you want to use for the `String` whenever those methods are called.

Comment: What @ochi said.  Most any modern IDE will offer either refactoring support that does exactly what you want (for instance, in Eclipse you can right-click any method and choose 'Refactor -> Change Method Signature'), or at the very least a global/project-wide 'Find/Replace' feature that can also be used to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse put your blinking cursor onto the method and hit `ctrl+shift+r`. This allows you to rename methods, variables etc -- whatever you have selected in the entire project.

EDIT: I misread your question.

You need to "change method signature". Most IDEs have similar features e.g., IntelliJ -- Right Click -- Refactor - Change Signature. If you do not have an IDE then you will have to write a script or manually change all the calls.

Comment: I just wanted to do programmatically. I am search for any api or open source framework which can provide these feature. and I am not interest to build any eclipse plugin but if we can reuse those jar fine for me as i want to run this utility outside of eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

if IDE provided refactoring is not option then I use Notepad++, it allows you to find and replace things without opening files, by selecting parent directory. I hope that will help you as well.